# GPU/CPU usage in dyntopo mode

Tags: gpu, sculpt

Quick question regarding GPU/CPU usage. When I am in sculpt and have dyntopo disabled my GPU shoots to 100% when I rotate view on a high vert model.
But when I enable dyntopo and rotate view it gets very laggy and neither GPU or CPU has any activity what so ever.
I'm just wondering why?